# How do you do async setup outside of a lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda

Config makes a call to the parameter store and returns a config object.  I need to wait before initialising mysql.

```
const config = require('./config');
const mysql = require('serverless-mysql')(config);

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  // mysql stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need to wait for this to happen?

```
const mysql = require('serverless-mysql')(config)??
```

If so, then do this:

```
const config = require('./config');

async function mySQLStuff() {

  try{
    const mysql = await require('serverless-mysql')(config);
  } catch (error) {
    //handle error
  }
 return mysql;
};

exports.handler = (event, context) => {

  mySQLStuff()
    .then((data) => //mysql stuff)

};
```

Comment: No, sorry was not clearer I'm waiting for the config call, as it contains the details for the mysql call.

Comment: What config call, you are waiting for the require('./config') ?

Comment: It's a library that calls the ssm parameter store.